# Get rows results sorted by 2 columns with Wordpress $wpdb

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have 'transactions' table:

```
id user amount currency plan_id
1   1     11     usd      1
2   1     9      usd      2
3   1     10     usd      2
4   2     10     usd      7
5   1     7      eur      3
6   1     5      eur      3
7   1     6      eur      4
8   3     3      usd      8
```

I would like to get the sum of the amounts sorted by currency and then plan_id per given user: `$results[currency][plan_id]`

```
$results['usd'][1] = 11
$results['usd'][2] = 19
$results['eur'][3] = 12
$results['eur'][4] = 6
```

so far I have:

```
$query = '
    SELECT plan_id, currency, SUM( amount ) as earnings
    FROM transactions
    WHERE user = 1
    GROUP BY currency, plan_id
';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT_K );
```

But it is returning just rows sorted regularly by plan_id ignoring the sorting by currency:

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [plan_id] => 1 [currency] => usd [earnings] => 11 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [plan_id] => 2 [currency] => usd [earnings] => 19 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [plan_id] => 3 [currency] => eur [earnings] => 12 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [plan_id] => 7 [currency] => eur [earnings] => 6 ) )
```

Is it even possible to do with `$wpdb`?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL how to sort the results using the [ORDER BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) (missing in your query).

This will yield the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT `plan_id`, `currency`, SUM( `amount` ) AS `earnings`
FROM `transactions`
WHERE `user` = 1
GROUP BY `currency`, `plan_id`
ORDER BY `currency` DESC, `plan_id` ASC
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best!